# Azure Event Grid - Resource Write Success - Filter by email address

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Azure Event Grid is used to capture all Azure `Resource Write Success` activities. I'm trying to filter users by email address.

`data.clamins.name` gives the username in similar way when tried `data.claims.'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name'` the filter is not working as expected.

Should there be escape characters to make `'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name'` filter work ?

This is used for below use case of tagging newly created resources for deletion

1. Event grid invoke azure automation script when there is a `Resource Write Success` event in Azure
2. Script tag resources with expire tag
3. A second script take care of deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, there is no either documented or undocumented way/workaround using this kind of naming in the advanced filtering. It will be nice to have it for claims, for instance:

```
data.claims.schemas_ws200505identity_emailaddress
```

where the **schemas_ws200505identity_** represents value of http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/

Anyway, for your solution the place for filtering this property is in the subscription handler. The following code snippet shows this example:

```
public static async Task Run(JObject eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
{
   // ...

   var emailaddress = eventGridEvent["data"]?["claims"]?["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"]?.Value<string>();
   log.LogInformation($"emailaddress = {emailaddress}");

   // ...

  await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Azure Automation to process event grid data. As you have suggested I'll add an email address based filter to powershell script to handle it for time being. @roman-kiss

Comment: Basically, you can use an advanced filtering in the subscription for pre-filtering process and in the handler the rest custom filtering by the code.

Comment: Based on your input, I made the feedback (issue) to MS Event Grid team, see the link https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49942

Comment: Great I'll follow up on that ticket to see if they suggest any work around